# Find last value in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 1d array and want to find the last value like this.

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])
# find the index that value(7) last appear.
np.argwhere(a >= 7).max()
# output 10
```

But it's suit for 1d array and how about 3d array.

```
b = np.tile(a.reshape(15,1,1), reps=(1,30,30))
# now b is 3d array and i want to use same way to the axis = 0 in 3d array.
np.argwhere(b >= 7)
# return a 2d array. It's not what i need.
```

Although I could use 'for' loop the other axis, but I want to solve it efficiently by numpy.

Comment: @StephenRauch Sorry, should be apply  .max()

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks, it works. But there is anthor question that if the value(a==7 in your example) does not exists in the array. It return the max array index, how solve it?

Comment: So what must it return if there isn't any element with the value `7` in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the last index, we can flip the order along all axes and then use `np.argmax()` on the matches. The idea with flipping is to make use of the efficient `np.argmax` that gets us the first matching index.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def last_match_index(a, value):
    idx = np.array(np.unravel_index(((a==value)[::-1,::-1,::-1]).argmax(), a.shape))
    return a.shape - idx - 1
```

Runtime test -

```
In [180]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100,100))

In [181]: last_match_index(a,7)
Out[181]: array([99, 99, 89])

# @waterboy5281's argwhere soln
In [182]: np.argwhere(a==7)[-1]
Out[182]: array([99, 99, 89])

In [183]: %timeit np.argwhere(a==7)[-1]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.67 ms per loop

In [184]: %timeit last_match_index(a,7)
1000 loops, best of 3: 861 µs per loop
```

If you are looking to get the last index along an axis, say `axis=0` and iterate along two axes, let's say the last two axes, we could employ the same methodology -

```
a.shape[0] - (a==7)[::-1,:,:].argmax(0) - 1
```

Sample run -

```
In [158]: a = np.random.randint(4,8,(100,100,100))
     ...: m,n,r = a.shape
     ...: out = np.full((n,r),np.nan)
     ...: for i in range(n):
     ...:     for j in range(r):
     ...:         out[i,j] = np.argwhere(a[:,i,j]==7)[-1]
     ...:         

In [159]: out1 = a.shape[0] - (a==7)[::-1,:,:].argmax(0) - 1

In [160]: np.allclose(out, out1)
Out[160]: True
```

Comment: It's return 1d array has three element. 2d array, I want to apply the same way on axia =0. Like every b[:, i,j] loop i and j.

Comment: @LiZiming Check out the edits added at the end of the post.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, to get the index of the last occurrence of 7, you would use:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1])

indices = np.argwhere(a== 7)
last_index = indices[-1]
# 10
```

Now if you had a 3-dimensional array, you can still use `np.argwhere` to get occurrences of 7, but each occurrence will be in 3-dimensional space. To get the last occurrence of 7, again you would write

```
b = np.tile(a.reshape(17,1,1), reps=(1,30,30))
np.argwhere(b==7)[-1]
# [10 29 29]
```

which returns exactly what you would expect.

Comment: 2d array, I want to apply the same way on axia =0. Like every b[:, i,j] loop i and j.